# jquery ajax request is hiding the div? and not working correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax

in my project jquery ajax request is working perfectly at first time,after that on second request  it is not working and also hiding the corresponding div
i have already tried **async,cache** but its not working still..

```
 <script language="javascript">

   function changeval(context) {
     $.ajax({
     type:'GET',
     cache: false,
     async: false,
     url:context+'/getOldItems',
     success:function(data) { 
              $( "#main-wrapper-2" ).html( data );

     },
        error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error" + errorThrown);
                }
   });
}


  </script>
```

**after first ajax request successfully loaded**
[image]

**on second request failed and also it hides the div**
[image]

Comment: repsone may also contain the same id #main-wrapper-2 ,so please check it

Comment: I think your second response is empty and overrides the first one. (  $( "#main-wrapper-2" ).html( data ); ) If the second one is always empty you can try  $( "#main-wrapper-2" ).append( $(data) );

Comment: no response doesnt contain same id

Comment: my second response will not make any changes the same page as the first requst i want to show

Answer (score 0):

The results of the ajax request are completely replacing the contents of #main-wrapper-2, that's why the first request works correctly. If the result of the second request is empty it will result in #main-wrapper-2 being emptied.

Try replacing

```
$( "#main-wrapper-2" ).html( data );
```

with

```
$( "#main-wrapper-2" ).append( data );
```